# Limitar tempo de gravação (MediaRecorder)

Tags: android

Olá, como o título diz quero limitar a gravação do meu codigo:

```
    private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;

    uploadAudio();
}
```

> aqui é onde dou a ordem de gravar

```
        mImageMic.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startRecording();
                    mRelative.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mTextGravando.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTextGravando.setText("Gravando...");
                    mCronometro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //Parte Importante
                    mCronometro.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    mCronometro.start();

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopRecording();
                    mRelative.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTextGravando.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                    mCronometro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //Parte Importante                       
                    mCronometro.stop();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

pensei em algo como se `mCronometro` for igual a `60000` milesegundos chamar o `stop` e o `upload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar o método nativo `setMaxDuration` do `MediaRecorder` quando definir o seu objeto. No seu caso:

```
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000);
```

Conforme documentação oficial:

> **void setMaxDuration(int max_duration_ms)** -  the maximum duration (in ms) of the recording session. Call this
>   after setOutFormat() but before prepare(). After recording reaches the
>   specified duration, a notification will be sent to the
>   MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener with a "what" code of
>   MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED and recording will be
>   stopped. Stopping happens asynchronously, there is no guarantee that
>   the recorder will have stopped by the time the listener is notified.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxDuration(int)

Comment: Eu tinha chegado neste resultado aqui, mais ta aceita a reposta, valeu!